# need random numbers in list using python code random.sample(range(1, 100), 3)

Tags: django, python-3.x, random, range

Can anyone tell me if this piece of code will produce only unique random numbers in a list :

```
random.sample(range(1, 100), 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> random.sample(population, k)

`Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence. Used for random sampling without replacement.`

To choose a sample from a range of integers, use an range() object as an argument

```
>>> import random
>>> print random.sample(range(1,100),3)
[77, 29, 45]
>>>
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample

Answer (score 2):

Yes sample is choosing unique numbers

Have a look
[here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample)